# TBB synchronization primitives?

Tags: c++, tbb

What does TBB use underneath for synchronization? I've been looking through the source, but I can't seem to find anything. (This is for Windows)

Comment: Not sure if this helps: _TBB concurrent containers utilize TBB user-level synchronization primitives and atomic operations._ from [here](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/faq/do-tbb-concurrent-containers-use-os-synchronization-objects)

Comment: This [document](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/2-3-Sync_-_Choosing_Appropriate_Synchronization_Primitives_to_Minimize_Overhead.pdf) may reveal some details; I'm fairly certain that TBB provides a portable abstraction layer for OS-specific primitives. Your question doesn't specify on which OS, so we may need to know that to provide a complete answer.

Comment: tbb has own atomic implementation but now it's [deprecated](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506277). Now you should rely on C++11 sync primitives